# php preg_split expression raises warning

Tags: php, regex, warnings, preg-split

One of my regular expressions raises warnings and I just can't figure out why or how to change the expression so that it works fine.
Do I have to escape anything? If yes, why and how? I would like to better understand...

```
$output = preg_split("/($beginDelimiter|$endDelimiter)/", $text);
```

`PHP Warning:  preg_split(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 15 in /home/tim/importer.php on line 539`

Thanks for any help!

edit:
$beginDelimiter contains `SRF53`
$endDelimiter contains `(`

the second one must be the problem, I understand... it needs to be escaped.

Comment: What are the values of these 2 variables ?

Comment: I added the values :) why is that question so bad to down vote it without even telling why it was down voted...? so arrogant... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), as your variables contains special characters that need to be escaped in `regex`.

> `preg_quote()` takes string and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.

```
$output = preg_split("/(".preg_quote($beginDelimiter)."|".preg_quote($endDelimiter)."/", $text);
```

Comment: I think `preg_quote()` would be the better function here. But OP still doesn't know which characters are so special..

Comment: yeah, had to wait 4 minutes last time I tried... haha everyone in a rush today, I suppose ;)